# R: how to convert delimited string with ranges with the actual numbers in the range?

Tags: r, dplyr, etl, tidyverse

I have a dataset looks like this:

[image]

So in the second row of the column'leaf_grade', we could see the value of '1-5', so in what I want is the row replicate 5 times with all the values on the row being the same except the 'leaf-grade' changes from 1 to 5.

So the output should look like:

```
Column 32    33    34       35    36    37    38     colour_grade  leaf_grade
       -775  -700  -625.00  -600  -600  -600  -600   61            1
       -775  -700  -625.00  -600  -600  -600  -600   61            2
       -775  -700  -625.00  -600  -600  -600  -600   61            3
       -775  -700  -625.00  -600  -600  -600  -600   61            4
       -775  -700  -625.00  -600  -600  -600  -600   61            5
```

Could we achieve this result in r? could we use dplyr to achieve this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841463/expand-a-data-frame-to-have-as-many-rows-as-range-of-two-columns-in-original-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` the 'leaf_grade' at `-` (assuming that it is a `character` class column), convert it to `numeric`, get the sequence with `reduce` and `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(leaf_grade = strsplit(leaf_grade, '-') %>%
                          map( ~ as.numeric(.x) %>%
                                 reduce(`:`))) %>% 
  unnest
```

Comment: unfortunately shows error "Error in rep(seq_nrow(data), w) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) : NAs introduced by coercion". Do you know the reason? @akrun

Comment: @Kristy.Z  Try with the updated code

Comment: @ akrun thanks that works! :)